# Risk ratio and risk difference using marginal standardisation in R

Tags: r, emmeans

I am trying to obtain a risk ratio and risk difference in R using marginal standardisation with the `emmeans` package.

Data is generated with:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(emmeans)

n_sites <- 10
centre <- factor(paste0("Site ", 1:n_sites))
age <- factor(c("3 months - <3 years", "3 years – 11 years"))
sex <- factor(c("Male", "Female"))

generate_dummy_dataset <- function(
    n = 705,
    centre_dist = rep(1, n_sites), 
    sex_dist = c(1, 1), 
    age_dist = c(1, 1)){
  data.frame(
    ID = 1001:(n + 1000),
    site = sample(centre, n, TRUE, centre_dist),
    rand_ageband = sample(age, n, TRUE, sex_dist),
    rand_sex = sample(sex, n, TRUE, age_dist)
  )
}

set.seed(420)

# Generate covariates
data <- generate_dummy_dataset(centre_dist = exp(seq(0, log(10), length.out = n_sites)), 
                                sex_dist = c(1, 3), 
                                age_dist = c(1, 3))

# Randomise
data <- cbind(data, duration = factor(sample(c(3, 5, 6, 8, 10), 705, TRUE)))

# Outcomes
data <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(eta = case_when(duration == 3 ~ log(0.5), 
                         duration == 5 ~ log(0.7), 
                         duration == 6 ~ log(0.8), 
                         duration == 8 ~ log(0.9),
                         duration == 10 ~ log(0.95)) +
           if_else(rand_ageband == "3 months - <3 years", log(1), log(1.5)) +
           if_else(rand_sex == "Female", log(1), log(1.5)),
         p = 1 / (1 + exp(-eta)),
         outcome = sample(c(0, 1), 1, TRUE, c(1 - p, p)))

data <- data %>%
  mutate(duration = forcats::fct_relevel(duration, "10"))
```

I plan to fit a logistic regression with `glm`, then get a probability of outcome using `emmeans`. From this, I want to get a risk difference and risk ratio (with 95% delta confidence intervals), comparing each `duration` to `10` (the reference). I don't want a multiplicity adjustment.

```
# Model
model_logistic <- glm(outcome ~ duration + rand_ageband + rand_sex, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = data)

emm <- emmeans(model_logistic, specs = ~ duration, type = "response")
```

I'm sure it can be done with `contrast`, but so far I can only make odds ratios:

```
contrast(emm, method = "pairwise", adjust = "none")
```

Any help?

Comment: This vignette might be of some use: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/risks/vignettes/margstd.html (it's not using emmeans, but maybe?)

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to do this in **emmeans**. Starting with your `emm` object, do:

```
lemm <- regrid(emm, "log")
pairs(lemm, type = "response")
```

The `regrid()` call redefines the estimates so that they are on the log scale. That is, each estimate in `lemm` is of the log of the probability, rather than its logit.

Second, when you have a log transformation and ask for contrasts on the response scale, you obtain ratios (in this case ratios of probabilities), because the difference of logs is the log of the ratio so you can back-transform those results to ratios.

Comment: To get risk differences, `regrid()` to `"response"`

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know how to do this in `emmeans`, but it is quite easy in `marginaleffects`. (Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.)

These links may be relevant:

- A detailed vignette on what the `avg_comparisons()` function does: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/comparisons.html
- A comparison of `marginaleffects` and `emmeans`: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/alternative_software.html#emmeans

```r
library(marginaleffects)
mod <- glm(outcome ~ duration + rand_ageband + rand_sex, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = data)


avg_comparisons(mod, comparison = "ratio")
# 
#          Term                                 Contrast Estimate Std. Error     z Pr(>|z|)     S 2.5 % 97.5 %
#  duration     3 / 10                                      0.705     0.0850  8.30   <0.001  53.1 0.539  0.872
#  duration     5 / 10                                      0.975     0.1011  9.64   <0.001  70.6 0.777  1.173
#  duration     6 / 10                                      0.922     0.0986  9.35   <0.001  66.6 0.729  1.115
#  duration     8 / 10                                      1.042     0.1059  9.85   <0.001  73.6 0.835  1.250
#  rand_ageband 3 years – 11 years / 3 months - <3 years    1.243     0.1153 10.79   <0.001  87.7 1.017  1.469
#  rand_sex     Male / Female                               1.228     0.0925 13.28   <0.001 131.2 1.047  1.409
# 
# Columns: term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high


avg_comparisons(mod, comparison = "difference")
# 
#          Term                                 Contrast Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)   S   2.5 %  97.5 %
#  duration     3 - 10                                    -0.1686     0.0568 -2.967  0.00301 8.4 -0.2799 -0.0572
#  duration     5 - 10                                    -0.0142     0.0583 -0.243  0.80766 0.3 -0.1285  0.1001
#  duration     6 - 10                                    -0.0445     0.0585 -0.762  0.44623 1.2 -0.1591  0.0700
#  duration     8 - 10                                     0.0242     0.0590  0.410  0.68198 0.6 -0.0914  0.1397
#  rand_ageband 3 years – 11 years - 3 months - <3 years   0.1069     0.0427  2.505  0.01225 6.4  0.0233  0.1906
#  rand_sex     Male - Female                              0.1119     0.0425  2.632  0.00850 6.9  0.0286  0.1953
# 
# Columns: term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high
```