Simple contrasts output from SPSS in R
I estimated a mixed model with the GENLINMIXED command in SPSS. In the model options I specified that I want to estimate simple contrasts for my interaction variable (category*group) by the variable "group". The output of the "simple contrasts" looks like this: 
I would like to get the same output in R where I estimate the model with glmer from the lme4 package. Does anyone know how to do that?

Can you please include your output in a text format rather than as a screenshot/image? (Cut and paste and include it as a code block delimited by triple-backticks (`).)

@BenBolker I'm really sorry but I couldn't figure out how to do that. When I click on the output in SPSS and copy it as "plain text" and then try to paste it here, I only have the option to inlcude it as an image.

That's too bad ... https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/discussion/how-to-copy-paste-text-between-spss-and-other-applications

In general you would use the emmeans package for this.  Here's an example using lm() and a built-in data set: it should work equally well for a glmer model, substituting ~group | category in the emmeans() statement and ref="0" (or something like that) in the contrast() statement.
library(emmeans)
warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool*tension, data = warpbreaks)
warp.emm <- emmeans(warp.lm, ~ tension | wool)
cc <- contrast(warp.emm, "trt.vs.ctrl", ref = "L")
summary(cc, infer = TRUE)  ## infer = TRUE to get CIs

You can choose the method of multiple comparisons correction using the adjust argument to summary(); I think you might use adjust = "tukey" to match your SPSS results, but I'm not sure.
wool = A:
 contrast estimate   SE df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 M - L     -20.556 5.16 48    -32.4    -8.74  -3.986  0.0005
 H - L     -20.000 5.16 48    -31.8    -8.19  -3.878  0.0006

wool = B:
 contrast estimate   SE df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 M - L       0.556 5.16 48    -11.3    12.37   0.108  0.9863
 H - L      -9.444 5.16 48    -21.3     2.37  -1.831  0.1338

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: dunnettx method for 2 estimates 
P value adjustment: dunnettx method for 2 tests 


Thank you very much for your kind help! I followed your suggestions, but I did not get the same results as in SPSS. In SPSS it shows the contrast estimate, which is the difference between probabilities from the emmeans function. However, in R it shows the odds ratios. Do you have an idea how to change that? Here is what I did: glmm <- glmer(DV ~ group*category + (1 | Id), data = df, family = binomial(link = "logit"),nAGQ = 0) emm <- emmeans(glmm,~group,by="category", type="response") cc <- contrast(emm, "trt.vs.ctrl",ref= length(emm)) summary(cc, infer = TRUE, adjust = "none")

showing differences between probabilities is a bit odd, statistically, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78614937/how-to-back-transform-inverse-transformation-in-emmeans-when-using-contrast-func/78617715#78617715

The link did not help very much unfortunately, but I was able to find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76589024/risk-ratio-and-risk-difference-using-marginal-standardisation-in-r: contrast(regrid(emm, "response"), "trt.vs.ctrl"). Thank you again for your help!
